# How do i get recent post from wordpress DB in my codeigniter controller?

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter-2

i have a **blog** developed in wordpress. And i also have a **site** which developed in PHP using code-igniter framework. 
Now i want to get 2 recent posts from **blog** DB to show them on my **cod-igniter site**.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you please post your code?

Comment: try using wordpress posts rss feed. like http://example.com/feed/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the curl and can fetch the posts to display on codeigniter like this
and this will fetch latest two posts

```html
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, Array(
 CURLOPT_URL            => 'http://example.com/feed/', //your website url
 CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'spider',
 CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
 CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
 CURLOPT_ENCODING       => 'UTF-8'
));
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
?>

<?php 
$i=0;
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
 echo '<h2>' . $item->title . '</h2>';
 echo '<p>' . $item->description . '</p>';
  
$i++;
if($i==2) break; //this will break loop after two iterations
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Select the recent post by using direct sql query or by using rest api of wordpress for recent post :

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC limit 2;
```

OR

**By using rest api**

```
http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=post_date&filter[posts_per_page]=2 //replace mywebsite.com with your site name.
```

I hope the above content will help you.